# Добавить предыдущее значение при выполнении условия в цикле python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

требуется получить предыдущее значение колонки С + 1 , если колонка B > 1 иначе, предыдущее значение колонки С. 
Первое значение в колонки С = 1.
Как я делал:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],"b":[0,5,1,0,1,0,6,0,2,0,0]})
df.loc[df1['a'] == df['a'].min(),'c'] = 1

for i in df1['b']:
    if i>1:
        df['c'] = df['c'].shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int)+1
    else:
        df['c'] = df['c'].shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int)     
df['c']= df['c'] + 1
df
```

Результат:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   0   1
1   2   5   1
2   3   1   2
3   4   0   2
4   5   1   3
5   6   0   3
6   7   6   3
7   8   0   3
8   9   2   3
9   10  0   4
10  11  0   4
```

Верный результат:

```
        a   b   c
    0   1   0   1
    1   2   5   2
    2   3   1   2
    3   4   0   2
    4   5   1   2
    5   6   0   2
    6   7   6   3
    7   8   0   3
    8   9   2   4
    9   10  0   4
    10  11  0   4
```

Можно рассмотреть другие варианте, без циклов. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],"b":[0,5,1,0,1,0,6,0,2,0,0]})
df['c'] = (df['b'].gt(1)).astype(int)
df['c'] = df['c'].cumsum().add(1)
```

результат:

```
     a  b  c
0    1  0  1
1    2  5  2
2    3  1  2
3    4  0  2
4    5  1  2
5    6  0  2
6    7  6  3
7    8  0  3
8    9  2  4
9   10  0  4
10  11  0  4
```